# Join on multiple fields in Access (SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have a fairly simply question, but I happen to know not enough to answer it myself. I have a table with monthly financial data and I have another table with which I do some mapping. In both tables I have the corresponding three fields / columns:

- JV Segment Account
- JV CAPEX TECH AREA
- Movement code

I need to join always on "Movement Code" but when JV Segment Account is "[None]" I need to join in combination with "JV Capex tech Area" and when "JV Capex tech area" is "[None]" I need to join with "JV Segment Account". So it's a double join (always including movement code but with a variable second join). Is it possible to do this in one query?

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Michiel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is one way to get your answer. To translate this back to your tables and fields:

- ID = Movement Code - which matches in both, thus the Inner Join
- FldA = JV Segment Account
- FldB = JV Capex tech area
- If fields match between tables, then select

  ```
  SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.FldA, Table1.FldB, Table2.FldA, Table2.FldB, 
      IIf([Table1].[FldA]=[Table2].[FldA],'Match',"") AS Same2, 
      IIf([Table1].[FldB]=[Table2].[FldB],'Match',"") AS Same3
      FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
      WHERE (((IIf([Table1].[FldA]=[Table2].[FldA],'Match',""))="Match")) 
      OR (((IIf([Table1].[FldB]=[Table2].[FldB],'Match',""))="Match"));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a union query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MonthlyFinancialTable f
INNER JOIN MapTable m
ON f.[Movement code] = m.[Movement code]
AND f.[JV CAPEX TECH AREA] = m.[JV CAPEX TECH AREA]
WHERE f.[JV Segment Account] = '[NONE]'

UNION ALL

SELECT * 
FROM MonthlyFinancialTable f
INNER JOIN MapTable m
ON f.[Movement code] = m.[Movement code]
AND f.[JV Segment Account] = m.[JV Segment Account]
WHERE f.[JV CAPEX TECH AREA] = '[NONE]'
```